# Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be nonempty and let $u \in \mathbb{R}$ be an upper bound.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that $u=\sup A$ iff there is a sequence $a_n$ in $A$ such that $a_n\to u$.

I am not quite sure if I can use monotone convergence thm to prove it but in the part of backward I don't know how to prove.

Comment: Hello - I have edited your post. Please clarify your question: What do you mean by "the part of backward"?

Comment: They probably mean the reverse implication.

Comment: I guess he means the converse part.

Comment: Let $A := \{ \frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then $(1/n)$ is a sequence in $A$ and $1/n \to 0$. But $0$ is not the supremum of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there is no sequence that converges to $u$. Then, you can find a  $\epsilon$ neighborhood around $u$ such that no point of A is in that neighborhood. Note: $\epsilon$ neighborhood is synonymous with "Set of all points within $\epsilon$ of $u$. This implies that all points of A have an even smaller upper bound than $u$ (no point can be greater because $u$ is upperbound. Therefore $u$ is not $sup A$.

If there is such a sequence and $v < u$ is an upperbound. Then let $\epsilon$ = $\frac{|u-v|}{2}$. Can you figure the rest from here?